# Usar o entry do tkinter em um input

Tags: python, tkinter

Usei esse código para dar um UPDATE no Postgres e funcionou.

Porém queria fazer uma janela com tkinter, preciso que o entry do tkinter vá para o input do código:

```py
import psycopg2
from tkinter import *

def querypg():
    query = input("insira a query: ")
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="unico", user="postgres", password="postgres")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

janela = Tk()
janela.title("query tools")
texto = Label(janela, text="insira seu código aqui")
texto.grid(column=0, row=0)
botao = Button(janela, text="Rodar código", command=querypg)
botao.grid(column=0, row=2)
codigo = Entry(janela, width=100)
codigo.grid(column=0, row=1)
janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma [função lambda](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp). Nesse caso, `codigo` deve ser declarado antes de `botao`. Reescrevi sua função para exemplificar.

```
from tkinter import *
    
def querypg(text):
    print(text)
    
janela = Tk()
janela.title("query tools")
texto = Label(janela, text="insira seu código aqui")
texto.grid(column=0, row=0)
codigo = Entry(janela, width=100)
codigo.grid(column=0, row=1)
botao = Button(janela, text="Rodar código", command=lambda: querypg(codigo.get()))
botao.grid(column=0, row=2)
janela.mainloop()
```

Entrada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Saída:

`foo`